# How many ways can you connect vertices in a graph?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose you have a closed hexagon. How many ways are there to connect six vertices inside (to place three edges) such that you don't "waste" an edge on a neighboring vertex?

So I was thinking that each vertex inside of a hexagon can be connected to 3 other vertices with the above constraint. This means there are a total of $18$ possible edges. Then the answer to the question simply becomes $18\choose3$ = $816$. However, we need to account for the fact that we're double counting in a lot of the cases, but I'm not sure how to do that. For example, if we have something like:

```
   1 ___ 2
   /     \
6 /       \ 3
  \       /
   \ ___ /
   5     4
```

Then $18\choose3$ will count `(1-3, 1-4, 1-5)` and `(3-1, 4-1, 5-1)` as unique, when really they represent the same matching.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question: Are all the following four cases valid? (1-4, 2-5, 3-6), (1-3, 4-6, 2-5), (1-3, 1-4, 2-5), (1-3, 1-4, 1-5). Also are we assuming we are creating exactly three extra edges and no more than three?

Comment: These are so-called "Dewar benzene structures". It would be easier to count them by hand, for there are not that many.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I'm certainly interested in extending the problem to more complex polygons, so that doesn't help.

Comment: @cr001 Yes, each of those cases is valid, but something like (1-4, 5-2, 3-6) would be the same as (1-4, 2-5, 3-6) (because 2-5 and 5-2 represent the same edge). Also, no, it won't be exactly three extra edges. I want to be able to generalize the problem for an n-point polygon adding m edges inside, but I thought this would help me do that.

Comment: Then consider https://oeis.org/A003436.

Comment: It might be better to ask about counting how many [perfect matchings](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerfectMatching.html) there are in a graph, since you are not actually "connecting" all the vertices (just pairing them off).  Necessarily there must be an even number of vertices to make this possible.  It is much easier to find a perfect matching than to count *all* of them, but for a polygon (cycle) with an even number of vertices, there will only be two perfect matchings.

Answer (score 0):

Each edge has two endpoints, so there are only $18/2 = 9$ possible edges. Hence there are $\binom{9}{3} = 84$ possible combinations of three internal edges.